# Qt: How to display Ctrl+W instead of Ctrl+F4 in the default system menu of a subwindow?

Tags: qt, menu, key, shortcut

some quick help is needed, as I am probably missing the trick that would help with this situation in Qt (I use the latest Qt 4).

Within my QMdiArea, I create a few subwindows. All the subwindows have the default system menu attached (minimize, maximize, stay on top, close, ... - that's seen when right-clicking on the subwindow icon).

To be consistent with what I have defined in the main menu of my application (ctrl+w visible for closing windows), **I cannot accept that the displayed shortcut related to Close is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> in the subwindows' system menu.** *It has to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>*. I have tried different things, including setting the shortcut global for the application (with setShortcutContext)... but no luck.

Close has by default two shortcuts: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. I want both to keep working, but it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> which should always be displayed.

For now, the only solution I see is to replace the system menu (a QMenu)... but that seem to be a lot of code for such a simple task!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting it this way:

```
ui->mdiArea->subWindowList().at(index)->systemMenu()->actions().last()->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_W));
```

Please replace "index" with suitable index.
It worked for me. (UPDATE: this does not work, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is already an assigned shortcut for close action)

UPDATE:

Close action has two assigned shortcuts, and the first one is displayed at menu. If you swap the order, you'll get <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> displayed.

```
QList<QKeySequence> closeShorcuts = ui->mdiArea->subWindowList().at(0)->systemMenu()->actions().last()->shortcuts();
closeShorcuts.swap(0, 1);
ui->mdiArea->subWindowList().at(0)->systemMenu()->actions().last()->setShortcuts(closeShorcuts);
```

Please note that there is no platform check in this source code; if you run this on MAC you'll get the opposite result, and in X11 it will go out of list bounds (because there is only one shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Luis! I thought earlier that a long line of calls to functions here and there would do the trick, without being able to figure how to do it: I missed that a QMenu is a QWidget; And hence The QWidget provides actions() (which returns a QList). I indeed see CTRL+W in my subwindow now.

Comment: When I select the Close menu item with the mouse, it works. However... when I try the shorcuts on the keyboard (CTRL+W and CTRL+F4), none works anymore (when this worked earlier). I tried various setShortcutContext options, but this did not help to fix this new related problem. Browsing through Qt docs and googling did not help either for now (still searching - just updating the case right now)

Comment: Ok, I removed the close action with: pSubWindow->systemMenu()->removeAction(pSubWindow->systemMenu()->actions().last()); ... and I actually appear to like my simplified subwindow that way now (there is already a close button). Since I already have a close action defined in the application, I suspected a conflict there, hence removing close and adding the already existing close action was I guess a valid possibility as well. Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: It also appears that if I want to prevent close shortcuts (ctrl+F4, ctrl+W) to repeat, the setAutoRepeat(false) is curiously best put before the removal of the action from the system menu of the subwindow: systemMenu()->actions().last()->setAutoRepeat(false);
systemMenu()->removeAction(systemMenu()->actions().last());

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.
It seems that conflicts with default shortcut, throwing following warning: "QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Ctrl+W".
That's because CTRL+W is already a shortcut (according to Qt default shortcuts, http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qkeysequence.html#standard-shortcuts)

But there is a trick that works: I'll edit my answer.